# how to include test with src inside artifact using Maven

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to create an artifact that includes my tests toegether with the src files.
my pom has the following plugin:
       
                org.apache.maven.plugins
                maven-jar-plugin
                2.4
                
                    
                        
                            test-jar
                            jar

but the result is that this create two artifacts, one with the src without the tests and the second one include only the tests.

is there any way to create just 1 artifact that include the test as well or maybe to copy the artifact to the artifact that include src

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is this an effort to produce a "source" release of your project, e.g. `pom.xml` plus all source files (test and non-test)?

Comment: the reason is that all of my project is for testing only, the release is only internal and is using by a tool that receive tests artifact and run them from the command line

Answer (score 0):

That's against the Maven convention. So the plugin most likely doesn't provide this.

Comment: Pretty much agree. You can specify `classesDirectory` to include sources AND test-sources but it's not really so clean.